# Generic xpath to access particular tab content if that exists

Tags: java, xpath, htmlcleaner

Below are the two web pages having tabs like "Features,Application and Benefits",here I want to
 extract the content of only "Features" tab. One webpage having "Features" in first tab and 
 other webpage have "Benefits" instead of "Features" tab.

http://www.eaton.com/Eaton/ProductsServices/Hydraulics/Accumulators/PCT_256248
http://www.eaton.com/Eaton/ProductsServices/Vehicle/Superchargers/RSeries/index.htm#tabs-2

**Tried Method:**
By using "below code" and the xpath("//a[span='Features']/../../../div/div") I am able to
 get content of all tabs which are present in the web page.But,my problem is I am **looking 
 for generic "xpath"** that should get content of only "Features" in a webpage and it should
 not display anything if "Features" tab is not present.

```
 HtmlCleaner htmCleaner = new HtmlCleaner();
   String s = "http://www.eaton.com/Eaton/ProductsServices/Hydraulics/Accumulators/PCT_256248";
   Document doc =  Jsoup.connect(s).timeout(30000).userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/15.0.874.120 Safari/535.2").get();
   String pageContent=doc.toString();
   TagNode node = htmCleaner.clean(pageContent);
   Object[] statsNode = node.evaluateXPath("//a[span='Features']/../../../div/div");
   for(int i=0;i<statsNode.length;i++){
   TagNode resultNode = (TagNode) statsNode[i];
   System.out.print(resultNode.getText());
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

Notice that the target `div` `id` corresponds to the `href` attribute of the tab header. For example, when the `href` attribute value is `"#tabs-1"`, the corresponding `div` `id` attribute value is `"tabs-1"`.

Taking advantage of that correlation, this is one possible XPath that will return `<div>` element that corresponds to `Features` link/tab or return nothing in absence of `Features` tab :

```
//div[concat('#', @id)=preceding::a[span='Features']/@href]
```

Comment: Hi har07,
really it was quick and on target reply but the xpath u suggested not working in HtmlCleaner which we were using, its throwing `org.htmlcleaner.XPatherException: Unknown function concat!`

tried with other options like string-join but the same exception, i know i am bothering u with this but i am new to this can u please help me this.

Comment: @user2250305 seems that you need to find a way other than XPath, because the library you're using only support a [very limited](http://htmlcleaner.sourceforge.net/doc/org/htmlcleaner/TagNode.html#evaluateXPath%28java.lang.String%29) XPath syntax, which I think insufficient to accomplish this task. Unfortunately, I'm not familiar with Java, let alone the HtmlCleaner library

Comment: If you use HtmlCleaner's JDom serializer you can then use JDom's XPath functionality, rather than the subset supported natively within HtmlCleaner